# Como puedo actualizar una propiedad en un objeto dentro de un array con mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentado actualizar un objeto dentro de un array y se ve de esta manera:

```
"settings" : [ 
    {
        "sound" : true,
        "music" : true
    }
]
```

Estoy usando el método $set modificando el valor de "sound" de "true" a "false", pero al realizar esta acción, la propiedad "music" desaparece.

```
await settings.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
    guildID: message.guild.id,
   },
   {
    $set: {
     settings: { sound: false },
    }
   },
);
```

Cualquier ayuda se aprecia, llevo un rato intentado averiguar esto, estoy buscando en la documentación de mongodb, pero no encuentro nada que me sirva.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB utiliza la notación de puntos para acceder a los elementos de una matriz.

Prueba acceder al elemento de la matriz por la posición de índice basada en cero. Encierra entre comillas concatenando el nombre de la matriz con la posición de índice basada en punto y el nombre del campo‎:

```
await settings.findOneAndUpdate(
 {
   guildID: message.guild.id,
 },
 {
   $set: { "settings.0.sound": false }
 },
);
```